# Android Gallery async image load

Tags: android, image, asynchronous, download, gallery

Is it possible to use async image loader from this project http://open-pim.com/tmp/LazyList.zip with Gallery widget?
I tried:

```
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView=new ImageView(activity.getBaseContext());

    imageLoader.DisplayImage(urlList.get(position), activity, imageView);

    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 150));

    return imageView;
}
```

but it had no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must tag your image views appropriately so the asynchronous task can update them once the images are retrieved from the cache or network:

```
imageLoader.DisplayImage(urlList.get(position), activity, imageView);
imageView.setTag(urlList.get(position));
```

Comment: I've added it and now I receive Runtime Exception in ImageLoader class here:  Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext(); that is class cast exception

Comment: Try just passing the activity object as context when you create the ImageView.

Answer (score 1):

The code below works fine for my project.

Use ViewHolder instead of new ImageView(Context c) every time, if you have 2 or more view in viewholder, just code like below(Uses findViewById()):

holder.iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv);

holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv);

And you'd better inflate a layout in xml, and code the views' styles.don't code in getView() as it's time sensitive.

Code modified from LazyList demo, I hope this works for you.Best wishes!

```
static class ViewHolder{
    ImageView iv;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View holder = null;
    if(convertView==null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.iv = (ImageView) convertView;
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], activity, holder.iv);
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> imageLoader.DisplayImage(urlList.get(position), activity, imageView);
>   imageView.setTag(urlList.get(position));

This code works fine. Can we use it to imageviews inside RemoteViews.